# Как пометить ссылку страницы на которой находишься

Tags: html, css, javascript

Не знаю, как пометить ссылку страницы на которой находишься. То есть, допустим, есть 3 ссылки. Главная, Страница 1, Страница 2. Когда ты зашел на главную, появилось подчеркивание у ссылки, ведущую на главную. Когда перешел на Страница 1, у ссылки, ведущую на Страница 1 появилось подчеркивание и т.п.

Comment: ссылка на саму себя - [Лебедев негодует][1]. Меню нужно генерить с сылками на другие страницы, а там где была ссылка на текущую страницу можно показывать, но ссылкой делать не стоит (а как вы ее будете выделять - зависит от вас).

[1]:http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/75/

Answer (score 1):

Покажу на примере меню. Пример html:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="selected">Элемент 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Элемент 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Элемент 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Далее украшиваем ссылки как хотим с помощью CSS. Пример:

```
#mainmenu a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

И пишем CSS для ссылки, которую мы хотим выделить (например она у нас будет не красная, а синяя, неподчеркнутая и по нажатию на нее не будет ничего происходить (это логично)):

```
 #mainmenu a.selected {
     color: blue;
     text-decoration: none;
     pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Осталось только добавлять атрибут class ссылке которая была нажата и убирать с ненужной. Это нужно делать c помощью jscript (или jquery). [Тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=668) можно почитать (с примерами) как это делается средствами jquery

Comment: И параметр href для такой ссылки можно убрать, тогда она перестанет реагировать на мышь