# Как сделать ссылку активной для каждой страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок меню:

```css
nav>ul>a {
  background: #eee;
  color: #010101;
}

nav>ul>a:active {
  background: #010101;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="/about">
      <li>about</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/info">
      <li>info</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Как сделать, чтобы на странице `/about`  ссылка `<a href="/about">` была активной, а на странице `/info` соответственно ссылка `<a href="/info">` была активной ?

Может скриптами есть решение этой задачи?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как пометить ссылку страницы на которой находишься](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105260/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%88%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: @Alex, ну и почему же это дубликат? Там только разметка, а откуда берётся класс, ничего нет. Тут спрашивают, как повесить класс. А ещё у того вопроса даже принятого ответа нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy что можешь предложить?

Comment: @Encode_VI, ты уже мой ответ принял. Разве чего-то ещё не хватает?

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос был "как сделать, чтобы ссылка была активной ", на странице с дубликатом решение через ручное навешивание класса к нужной ссылке. Это не означает, что это единственное верное решение. А то, что ответ не принят, совсем не говорит о том, что это не решение.

Comment: Ребятки, все приятно и я при многом вам благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var curpath = location.pathname.match(/^\/[^/]+/);
var link = curpath && document.querySelector('nav a[href="' + curpath[0] + '"]');

if (link) {
  link.className += ' active';
}
```

```css
nav a {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  color: #010101;
}

nav a.active {
  background: #010101;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js">js</a></li>
    <li><a href="/info">info</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ))